# How to pass execution arguments to exe using PM2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 to start a `.exe` but I'm not able to pass argument to it.

The command I am using is `pm2 start go-cqhttp_windows_amd64.exe -- -faststart`. But it doesn't work.I want to pass the parameter `-faststart` to this program.Thanks!

Comment: Pass args after `--`. Are you sure the arg name expected by the exe is `-faststart` and not `--faststart`? Usually single dash args are one letter.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure it's `-faststart` , which is given in the official document of this program